# Workbooks.open method giving exception - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

[image: WindowsExplorer image]

[image: VisualStudioErrorScreenShot]

I am trying to open excel through below code , but getting error on line :

```
string excelFile = @"‪‪D:\Hello.xlsx";
Workbook xlWorkbook = (Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
```

**Excel version** : MS Office Professional plus 2016

**Error :**
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ExcelHighlight.exe
Additional information: Sorry, we couldn't find ‪‪D:\Hello.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

**Code :**

```
 try

        {
            string FullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("Words.xml");
            string[] arr = XDocument.Load(FullPath).Descendants("Highlight").Descendants().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

            Application xlApp = new Application();
            string excelFile = @"‪‪D:\Hello.xlsx";
            Workbook xlWorkbook = (Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
            Sheets sheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
            string str;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            Worksheet xlWorkSheet4;
            Range range;
            xlWorkSheet4 = (Worksheet)sheet.get_Item(1);
            Range last3 = xlWorkSheet4.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            range = xlWorkSheet4.get_Range("A1", last3);
            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    if (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value2 is string)
                    {
                        str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value2;
                        if (str == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("null");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str.Replace("\\", "");
                            string[] words = str.Split(' ');
                            foreach (string arrs in arr)
                            {
                                foreach (string word in words)
                                {
                                    if (word == arrs)
                                    {

                                        var cell = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range);

                                        cell.Font.Bold = 1;
                                        cell.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("not string");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your Windows Explorer, showing the `Hello.xlsx` file located in the `D:\ ` folder.

Comment: Updated screenshot of windows explorer and visualstudio error on top of question.

Comment: Yes , i checked it is "D:\Hello.xlsx". and my system windows is "Windows 10"

Comment: You'll have to put Explorer into programmer mode.  Use Control Panel > File Explorer Options > View tab and untick the "Hide extensions for known file types" checkbox.  Now you can *see* a basic mishap like this file actually being named Hello.xls

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the string specified in the code to the `Process.Start` method. If the file still can't be found you need to check the file extension and remove the `@` symbol from the beginning (remove verbatim strings) and use the following path instead:

```
string excelFile = "‪‪D:\\Hello.xlsx";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute file path with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:

```
String fullFilepath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```